# How to add the pages and its hyperref for every reference?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to add the page(s) and its hypereference to every reference. I am already using this code, but it is not working:

```
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

My main code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

% Omitting Page Numbers
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

% Packages
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4.9cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
%\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{afterpage}  % blank pages
\usepackage{multirow}  % table
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % table
\usepackage{xpatch}  % table
\usepackage{tabu}  % table
\usepackage{hhline}  % cell color does not overlap cell line
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % headers
\usepackage{breakcites}  % references do not go though margins
\usepackage{sectsty}  % change chapter title size
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % four level contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % numbered four level contents
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % math
\usepackage{amsmath}  % math
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}  % references


% novas coisas que adicionei
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym} % acrónimos
% \usepackage{xltabular}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
%\makeglossaries
%\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
%\addto\captionsportuguese{%
%\def\acronymname{Sigasl, Acrónimos e Abreviaturas}
%}
% coisas novas terminam aqui

%\newcommand{\rectangle}{{  % rectangle
%  \ooalign{$\sqsubset\mkern3mu$\cr$\mkern3mu\sqsupse%t$\cr}
%}}

%\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

% References
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=MidnightBlue,
   filecolor=MidnightBlue,
   citecolor=BrickRed,
   urlcolor=MidnightBlue,
   bookmarksopen=true,
   linktocpage=true,
   pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
   pdfstartpage=1
}

% Blank Page
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage}

% Hide Blank Pages Numbers + Headers
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}

% Space between numbers and text
\geometry{footskip=2.45cm}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\newgeometry{left=3cm, right=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=1.2cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9}

%\include{parts/capa_provisoria}
\include{parts/capa_provisoria}

\afterpage{\blankpage}

\endgroup

% Preamble for Thesis
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=4.9cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage  % hide blank pages numbers + headers

\include{parts/acknowledgements}

%\include{parts/resumo}

\include{parts/abstract}

\include{parts/resumo_alargado}

\include{parts/contents}

\include{parts/list_of_figures}

\include{parts/list_of_tables}

\include{parts/list_of_abbreviations}

\afterpage{\blankpage}

% After Introductory Pages
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4.9cm,headsep=1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 

\chaptertitlefont{\Huge} % to fit chapter title to one line
\chapternumberfont{\Huge} 

\include{parts/introduction}

\include{parts/theoretical_framework}

\include{parts/literature_review}

\include{parts/data_and_methods}

\include{parts/results}

\include{parts/discussion}

\include{parts/conclusion}

%\include{parts/appendix}

%\include{parts/a_silver_standard_corpus_of_phenotype_gene_relations}

%\include{parts/extracting_phenotype-gene_relations}

%\include{parts/conclusion}

\pagestyle{plain}  % no more header 

\include{parts/references}

\end{document}
```

Then, in my reference tex, I have:

```
\newpage
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

And Finally, in my references.bib I have:

```
@article{ref1,
author = {Sadoughi, Farahnaz and Khodaveisi, Taleb},
year = {2018},
month = {11},
title = {The used theories for the adoption of electronic health record: a systematic literature review},
journal = {Health and Technology},
doi = {10.1007/s12553-018-0277-8}
}

@article{ref2,
author = {Weiskopf, Nicole and Weng, Chunhua},
year = {2012},
month = {06},
title = {Methods and dimensions of electronic health record data quality assessment: Enabling reuse for clinical research},
volume = {20},
journal = {Journal of the American Medical Informatics Association : JAMIA},
doi = {10.1136/amiajnl-2011-000681}
}
```

And I do call every citation in using "\cite{ref1}", for example.

I want to look like this, but it does not appears the number one, for example. I thought I just need this " \usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref} " but apparently is not enough. Anyone can help me, please?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Show a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem. Remove unneeded packages and code. Side remark: don't use the tabu package it is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: @ululrike Fischer the exact problem is that the number of the pages where the reference is does not appear, like that image example that I put. In the example, number 1 is refering to where the reference was mentioned. However, I cannot do that in my code.

Comment: I do understand your problem. But I have neither the time nor the will to convert your large document and the other snippets in a sensible, short test document. Large parts of your code are unrelated and unneeded to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. How can I help you? I just added the main code because there could be an error that I couldn't detect. In addition, I thought that to place the pages in each reference it would only take one line of code.So how can I help?

Comment: Well take one line in your code, e.g. `\include{parts/results}` remove it, and test if the problem is still there. Then do the same with the next line and so on. see also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe. And learn to ping people correctly.